# How to focus for data based on regular function

Tags: python

I am trying to focus for data from  a specific file based on regular expression. This is my function:

```
import re
Log_File='Path_file.log'
signal_sync='Timestamp\s([0-9]*)\s\sID=(\w{18})0*\sDest_ID=(\w{18})0*\sri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event\s([0-9]*)s'
fsrc = open(Log_File, 'r')
buff = fsrc.read()
fsrc.close()

list_info = re.findall(signal_sync, buff)
print('list_info=  '+str(list_info))
print('list_info_length=  '+str(len(list_info)))
```

Example of log file lines:

```
Timestamp 1547226466  ID=141592cc00000004 Dest_ID=ffff00ffffffffff ri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event 74
Timestamp 1547227958  ID=141592cc00000001 Dest_ID=ffff00ffffffffff ri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event 2738
Timestamp 1547227958  ID=141592cc00000001 Dest_ID=ffff00ffffffffff ri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event 2739
Timestamp 1547227958  ID=141592cc00000001 Dest_ID=ffff00ffffffffff ri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event 2740
```

But the result is:

```
list_info=  []
list_info_length=  0
```

I doubt about Dest_ID representation: 
I need that the result of my regular expression looks like this for example for the first line:

```
('Timestamp','141592cc00000004','ffff00ffffffffff','74')
```

Comment: Do you want just to check entries existence or extract some specific data?

Comment: I want to extract data that respect my regular expression

Comment: your regular expression is flawed, can we get the exact data you want ? Give an example with the first line of the log what should the expected output be.

Comment: @HadiFarah  I put already an example in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
signal_sync=r'\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{16})\s+Dest_ID=(\w{16})\s+ri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event\s+([0-9]+)'
```

`Timestamp` value,`ID`, `Dest_ID`, and event trigger count are group captured so if you want to use their values later on it's possible.

Using this I get the result:

```
list_info=  [('1547226466', '141592cc00000004', 'ffff00ffffffffff', '74'), ('1547227958', '141592cc00000001', 'ffff00ffffffffff', '2738'), ('1547227958', '141592cc00000001', 'ffff00ffffffffff', '2739'), ('1547227958', '141592cc00000001', 'ffff00ffffffffff', '2740')]
list_info_length=  4
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but  I need to put all data as regular expression result, for example: ('Timestamp','141592cc00000004','ffff00ffffffffff','74')

Comment: @dina fixed the regex, but instead of `Timestamp` I printed the values after it. If you actually want the word "Timestamp" just remove the brackets from `([0-9]+)` after Timestamp in the regex and put them around the word like so `(Timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

try this expression. Your has few mistakes

```
 signal_sync=r'Timestamp\s([0-9]*)\s\sID=(\w{16})0*\sDest_ID=(\w{16})0*\sri5_Receiver_trigger_for_the_end_of_Data_Frame_Reception_event\s([0-9]*)
```

Comment: ('1547226466', '141592cc00000004', 'ffff00ffffffffff', '74') - my output... Are u sure u need Timestamp in output?